# Rule conjI to split all the terms

Tags: isabelle

The rule conjI splits a conjunction as follows:

```
show "A ^ B ^ C ^ D"
proof(rule conjI)
  show "A" sorry
next 
  show "C ^ D" sorry"
```

Is there any rule that splits all the terms connected by the conjunction? Some like:

```
show "A ^ B ^ C ^ D"
proof(rule ?)
  show "A" sorry
next 
  show "C" sorry"
next 
  show "D" sorry"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with a single rule application, but you can do `intro conjI` to apply it exhaustively.

There's also the method `safe` that does a variety of things like this (split products, apply appropriate introduction/elimination rules etc).